# Cosmos Data migration tool throws Error while Migrating data from SQL Database to Azure Cosmos DB Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm Trying to import the data from SQL Database to Cosmos Db but it throws an error as Service is currently unavailable. I have no idea why it's showing this error. Azure Cosmos DB Emulator is also On. The error is as follows

[image]

[image]

[image]

$ Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceUnavailableException: Service is currently unavailable.
ActivityId: 9b40c18a-28ed-4945-b356-abaac18a1139 ---> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GoneException: The requested resource is no longer available at the server.
ActivityId: 9b40c18a-28ed-4945-b356-abaac18a1139
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoreReader.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.QuorumReader.d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.QuorumReader.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReplicatedResourceClient.d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReplicatedResourceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<b__0>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClassd`1.<b__c>d__f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__16.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__12`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReplicatedResourceClient.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoreClient.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.d__2e9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryClient.d__a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.d__e.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DefaultDocumentQueryExecutionContext.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__1>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.<ExecuteWithRetryPolicy>d__1b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DefaultDocumentQueryExecutionContext.<ExecuteInternalAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.<ExecuteNextAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1.d__17`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDb.Client.DocumentQueryExtensions.<FirstOrDefault>d__0`1.MoveNext() in f:_Bld\12470\6357\Sources_repo\DocumentDb\Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDb\Client\DocumentQueryExtensions.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDb.Client.DocumentDbClient.d__26.MoveNext() in f:_Bld\12470\6357\Sources_repo\DocumentDb\Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDb\Client\DocumentDbClient.cs:line 185
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDb.Client.DocumentDbClient.d__2.MoveNext() in f:_Bld\12470\6357\Sources_repo\DocumentDb\Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDb\Client\DocumentDbClient.cs:line 46
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDb.Sink.Parallel.DocumentDbParallelSinkAdapter.d__0.MoveNext() in f:_Bld\12470\6357\Sources_repo\DocumentDb\Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDb\Sink\Parallel\DocumentDbParallelSinkAdapter.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDb.Sink.Parallel.DocumentDbParallelSinkAdapterInternalFactory.d__0.MoveNext() in f:_Bld\12470\6357\Sources_repo\DocumentDb\Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDb\Sink\Parallel\DocumentDbParallelSinkAdapterInternalFactory.cs:line 30
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Core.Service.DataTransferService.d__9.MoveNext() in f:_Bld\12470\6357\Sources_repo\Core\Microsoft.DataTransfer.Core\Service\DataTransferService.cs:line 70
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.WpfHost.Steps.Import.ImportStep.d__8.MoveNext() in f:_Bld\12470\6357\Sources_repo\Wpf\Microsoft.DataTransfer.WpfHost\Steps\Import\ImportStep.cs:line 73

Comment: What do you mean, by "SQL"? Cosmos DB SQL API? or SQL Database? From your question, it's unclear (this isn't included at all in your question; please edit). Also, this really isn't a programming question; more of a tool usage question.

Comment: it's SQL Database. I have updated the question. @DavidMakogon

Comment: Right so... show where you're configuring for SQL Database. Without more details, you'll only get guesses. Maybe it's an incorrect connection string. Maybe you haven't properly set the SQL DB server firewall rules. Could be anything, really.

Comment: I have Verified both the connection string for SQL Database and Cosmos database in the migration tool. I have not change any of the firewall rules. if I have to check which rules should I check for? @DavidMakogon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the connection Mode in the Advanced Settings of the Target Information tab from DirectTCP to Gateway.